# Matlab: Plot points and make them clickable to display informations about it

Tags: matlab, callback, plot, figure

I have some points like this:

```
matrix = rand(6, 4)
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557
0.9134    0.9649    0.1419    0.0357
0.6324    0.1576    0.4218    0.8491
0.0975    0.9706    0.9157    0.9340
```

the first two columns are x and y values which get plotted as points via

`plot(matrix(:, 1), matrix(:, 2), '*r'`

Now what I want to work out is the following:
Whenever I click on a certain point in the plot, I want the information out of column 3 and 4 being displayed as text just right of the point in a box, e.g. with some text, e.g.
`information 1: VALUE_COL3, information 2: VALUE_COL4`. How to achieve that? I thought of the `ButtonDownFcn` attribute and than check out the clicked point and match it. But is there any easier way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MATLAB figures have a feature called *data cursors*. On the toolbar, there's a button that looks like a a blue curve, with a crosshair above it and a little tooltip. If you click this and then select one of the points you plotted, you'll get a little tooltip above the point giving some information about that point. You can double-click on the tooltip to pick it up, and rag it across to other plotted points.

By default, the tooltip displays simple information about the points, namely their X and Y coordinates. But you can customise the text displayed to whatever you want, by getting a handle to the `datacursormode` object of the figure used for plotting, and setting its `UpdateFcn`. The `UpdateFcn` callback is executed to determine the text displayed on the tooltip - in your case it could get the corresponding values from the third and fourth columns of your matrix, splice them together with the string "information", and return that for display.

See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datacursormode.html) example in the documentation to see how that can be done in more detail.

Comment: thanks that's awesome! Works pretty well when passing input arguments to the callback function, select the corresponding row and than displaying the informations!

Answer (score 8):

While Sam's method is probably the correct solution here, I'd like to offer another one (although it is more of a 'hack' than a proper solution).

You can attach context menus to handle graphics objects. These menus can display multiple selections and even let your script respond to user selections. Take a look at the following example:

```
x = [1:10];
y = x.^2;

plot(x,y); hold on;
h = plot(x(5), y(5),'ro'); %% save the handle to the point we want to annotate

hcmenu = uicontextmenu;
item1 = uimenu(hcmenu, 'Label', 'info 1');
item2 = uimenu(hcmenu, 'Label', 'info 2');
item3 = uimenu(hcmenu, 'Label', 'info 2');

set(h, 'uicontextmenu', hcmenu);
```

When you **right** click on the 'o' point, you get the context menu:

[image: Produces this...]

More information can be found at the [Mathwork's site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontextmenu.html).