# Make clicking MATLAB plot markers plot subgraph

Tags: matlab, plot, interactive, marker, clickable

In Matlab 2011b, I have a multidimensional matrix which is to be initially presented as a 2D plot of 2 of its dimensions. I wish to make the markers clickable with the left mouse button. Clicking on a marker draws a new figure of other dimensions sliced by the clicked value.

This question is related to [Matlab: Plot points and make them clickable to display informations about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442659/matlab-plot-points-and-make-them-clickable-to-display-informations-about-it) but I want to run a script, not just pop up data about the clicked point.

Googling hinted that `ButtonDownFcn` could be used, but examples I found require manually plotting each point and attaching a handler, like so:

```
hp = plot(x(1), y(1), 'o');
set(hp, 'buttondownfcn', 'disp(1)');
```

As there are many markers in the main graph, is it possible to just attach a handler to the entire curve and call the subgraph-plotting function with the index (preferable) or coordinates of the marker clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an idea of what you need, and should help get you started if I understand your requirements.

In this case, when you select a curve, it will draw it in the bottom subplot preserving the color.

```
function main
subplot(211)
h = plot (peaks);

set (h,'buttondownfcn', @hitme)
end

function hitme(gcbo,evendata)
subplot (212)
hold on;

col = get (gcbo,'Color');
h2 =  plot (get (gcbo,'XData'),get (gcbo,'YData'));
set (h2,'Color', col)

pt = get (gca, 'CurrentPoint');
disp (pt);
end
```

You can explore your options for get by simply writing `get(gcbo)` in the `hitme` function.

Comment: Thanks. Though your example shows how I can get a 2D slice of 3D data, I am more interested in getting the index of the marker of a 2D graph that I click on. For example, modifying your code below, clicking any marker prints the same XData and YData. I would like to get the index (1, 2, 3, etc) of the marker clicked instead.
function main
    data = peaks;
    h = plot (1:size(data,2), data(1,:), 'o-');
    set (h, 'buttondownfcn', @hitme)
end

function hitme (gcbo, evendata)
    get (gcbo, 'XData')
    get (gcbo, 'YData')
end

Comment: if all you want is the point, add `pt = get (gca, 'CurrentPoint');`, as shown above. It will give you a 3D point, so depending on your need, just use the first row.

Comment: Many thanks! It gives me the coordinates, rather than the index of the marker, but since I know the original matrix, I can calculate the index from the x-coordinate e.g. round(pt(1)) .